# Anchor Tags in EE 1.7

Tags: html

I am trying to connect a page by anchor and having no luck.

Here is my code :

```
<a href="{site_url}our_courses#953/">Name of Link</a>
```

and it's not working with this:

```
<a name="{category_id}"></a>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently EE puts a trailing slash at the end of the url. I will have to figure out how to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML has a trailing slash in it--EE wouldn't be the trailing slash in, in this context.

So, change this:

```
<a href="{site_url}our_courses#953/">Name of Link</a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="{site_url}our_courses#953">Name of Link</a>
```

And, you should end up with http://example.com/our_courses#953 as the output URL.